# Numpy drawing from urn

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, random

I want to run a relatively simple random draw in numpy, but I can't find a good way to express it.
I think the best way is to describe it as drawing from an urn without replacement. I have an urn with k colors, and n_k balls of every color. I want to draw m balls, and know how many balls of every color I have.

My current attempt it

`np.bincount(np.random.permutation(np.repeat(np.arange(k), n_k))[:m], minlength=k)`

here, `n_k` is an array of length k with the counts of the balls.

It seems that's equivalent to
`np.bincount(np.random.choice(k, m, n_k / n_k.sum(), minlength=k)`

which is a bit better, but still not great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want is an implementation of the [multivariate hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution).
<strike>I don't know of one in numpy or scipy, but it might already exist out there somewhere.</strike>

I contributed an implementation of the multivariate hypergeometric distribution to numpy 1.18.0; see [`numpy.random.Generator.multivariate_hypergeometric`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.multivariate_hypergeometric.html).

For example, to draw 15 samples from an urn containing 12 red, 4 green and 18 blue marbles, and repeat the process 10 times:

```
In [4]: import numpy as np

In [5]: rng = np.random.default_rng()

In [6]: colors = [12, 4, 18]

In [7]: rng.multivariate_hypergeometric(colors, 15, size=10)                    
Out[7]: 
array([[ 5,  4,  6],
       [ 3,  3,  9],
       [ 6,  2,  7],
       [ 7,  2,  6],
       [ 3,  0, 12],
       [ 5,  2,  8],
       [ 6,  2,  7],
       [ 7,  1,  7],
       [ 8,  1,  6],
       [ 6,  1,  8]])
```

The rest of this answer is now obsolete, but I'll leave for posterity (whatever that means...).

---

You can implement it using repeated calls to [`numpy.random.hypergeometric`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.hypergeometric.html).  Whether that will be more efficient than your implementation depends on how many colors there are and how many balls of each color.

For example, here's a script that prints the result of drawing from an urn containing three colors (red, green and blue):

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np


nred = 12
ngreen = 4
nblue = 18

m = 15

red = np.random.hypergeometric(nred, ngreen + nblue, m)
green = np.random.hypergeometric(ngreen, nblue, m - red)
blue = m - (red + green)

print("red:   %2i" % red)
print("green: %2i" % green)
print("blue:  %2i" % blue)
```

Sample output:

```
red:    6
green:  1
blue:   8
```

The following function generalizes that to choosing `m` balls given an array `colors` holding the number of each color:

```
def sample(m, colors):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    m : number balls to draw from the urn
    colors : one-dimensional array of number balls of each color in the urn

    Returns
    -------
    One-dimensional array with the same length as `colors` containing the
    number of balls of each color in a random sample.
    """

    remaining = np.cumsum(colors[::-1])[::-1]
    result = np.zeros(len(colors), dtype=np.int)
    for i in range(len(colors)-1):
        if m < 1:
            break
        result[i] = np.random.hypergeometric(colors[i], remaining[i+1], m)
        m -= result[i]
    result[-1] = m
    return result
```

For example,

```
>>> sample(10, [2, 4, 8, 16])
array([2, 3, 1, 4])
```

Comment: cool. Very interesting solution, thanks! If only there was a multinomial hypergeometric ;)

Comment: Right, `sample` is basically an implementation of the multivariate hypergeometric distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution).

Comment: Note that pymc provides a function (`rmultivariate_hypergeometric`) for drawing random variates from the multivariate hypergeometric.  Link is here: http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/_modules/pymc/distributions.html

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
def make_sampling_arr(n_k):
    out = [ x for s in [ [i] * n_k[i] for i in range(len(n_k)) ] for x in s ]
    return out

np.random.choice(make_sampling_arr(n_k), m)
```

Comment: I want the counts, you you need to call bincount at the end. And ``make_sampling_arr`` is the same as ``np.repeat``, as I used it above, right?