# Efficient use of numpy.random.choice with repeated numbers and alternatives

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, casting, repeat

I need to generate a large array with repeated elements, and my code is:

```
np.repeat(xrange(x,y), data)
```

However, data is a numpy array with type float64 (but it represent integeres, no 2.1 there) and I get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Exemple:

```
In [35]: x
Out[35]: 26

In [36]: y
Out[36]: 50

In [37]: data
Out[37]: 
array([ 3269.,   106.,  5533.,   317.,  1512.,   208.,   502.,   919.,
     406.,   421.,  1690.,  2236.,   705.,   505.,   230.,   213.,
     307.,  1628.,  4389.,  1491.,   355.,   103.,   854.,   424.])
In [38]: np.repeat(xrange(x,y), data)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call    last)
<ipython-input-38-105860821359> in <module>()
----> 1 np.repeat(xrange(x,y), data)

/home/pcadmin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy    /core/fromnumeric.pyc in repeat(a, repeats, axis)
394         repeat = a.repeat
395     except AttributeError:
--> 396         return _wrapit(a, 'repeat', repeats, axis)
397     return repeat(repeats, axis)
398 

/home/pcadmin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy  /core/fromnumeric.pyc in _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
 46     except AttributeError:
 47         wrap = None
---> 48     result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
 49     if wrap:
 50         if not isinstance(result, mu.ndarray):

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

I solve it by changing the code to

```
np.repeat(xrange(x,y), data.astype('int64'))
```

However, this is now one of the most expensive lines in my code!! Is there another alternative?

By the way, I using this inside

```
np.random.choice(np.repeat(xrange(x,y), data.astype('int64')), z)
```

in order to get a sample without replacement with size z of the integers between x and y, with the number of each given in data. I guess this is the best approach for that also right?

Comment: Could you provide a sample case? So, some sample values for `x,y,data,z`?

Comment: if your data is an array type, you can simply wrap it in numpy array with a dtype set, eg. `np.asarray(data, dtype='int64')`

Comment: Sorry, I will edit in the question. data is an numpy array already

Comment: yes, but in order to use `np.repeat`, you have to cast your data elements to int type as the repeater. So wrap your `new_data = np.asarray(data, dtype='int64'); np.repeat(..., new_data)`

Comment: with data as a very large array (say, >100000 entries) is coping it to new_data better than my solution (data.astype("int64") ) ?

Comment: If you are looking for `without replacement`, shouldn't you use `replace=False`, because the default value is `replace=True`?

Comment: Also, give us a sample `z`?

Comment: Very true!! Thanks a lot, I missed that the default was True.

Comment: Ok... In the real problematic data, the difference between x and y is arround 100000, the total number of elements ,(y-x)*data, is <10^8 but >10^4, and z in smaller than 10^6, (usually around 10^4)

Comment: @DiogoSantos, I don't think you understand what I meant. The problem you have is that you try to cast an array of floats directly to ints `data.astype('int64')` -- which are unsafe. My suggestion is to cast your array elements from float to ints "safely", then you can do your `np.repeat`

Comment: @Anzel I understand that. In my case, although it is unsafe, I'm sure it works, in the sense that my solution `data.astype('int64')` always works, is just slow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lurking in the question is the [multivariate hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution).  In [Numpy drawing from urn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734026/numpy-drawing-from-urn/35735195#35735195), I implemented a function that draws samples from this distribution.  I suspect it is very similar to the solution @DiogoSantos described in an answer.  Diogo says that using this approach is slow, but I find the following to be faster than Divakar's `optmized_v1`.

Here is a function that uses `sample(n, colors)` from the linked answer to implement a function with the same signature as Divakar's functions.

```
def hypergeom_version(x, y, z, data):
    s = sample(z, data)
    result = np.repeat(np.arange(x, y), s)
    return result
```

(This returns the values in *sorted order*.  If you need the values to be in random order, add `np.random.shuffle(result)` before the return statement.  It does not change the execution time significantly.)

Comparison:

```
In [153]: x = 100

In [154]: y = 100100

In [155]: z = 10000

In [156]: data = np.random.randint(1, 125, (y-x)).astype(float)
```

Divakar's `optimized_v1`:

```
In [157]: %timeit optimized_v1(x, y, z, data)
1 loop, best of 3: 520 ms per loop
```

`hypergeom_version`:

```
In [158]: %timeit hypergeom_version(x, y, z, data)
1 loop, best of 3: 244 ms per loop
```

If the values in `data` are larger, the relative performance is even better:

```
In [164]: data = np.random.randint(100, 500, (y-x)).astype(float)

In [165]: %timeit optimized_v1(x, y, z, data)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.91 s per loop

In [166]: %timeit hypergeom_version(x, y, z, data)
1 loop, best of 3: 246 ms per loop
```

Comment: Pretty interesting idea that drawing samples with max limits on each elem and a target sum (at least that's what it looks like to me)!

Comment: That is really very close to my implementation :) good to know! I can time it later, but what I found was that, if data is composed of many entries, with very small numbers each, is faster to use Divakar solution. You can imagine the extreme case in which data is a large array of 1.

Answer (score 5):

### Problem statement

Pretty interesting problem this one! Just to give the readers an idea about the problem without going into the minor data conversion issues, we have a range of values, let's say `a = np.arange(5)`, i.e.

```
a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
```

Now, let's say we have another array with the number of repetitions listed for each of the `5` numbers in `a`. So, let those be :

```
reps = np.array([2,4,6,2,2])
```

Next up, we are performing those repetitions :

```
In [32]: rep_nums = np.repeat(a,reps)

In [33]: rep_nums
Out[33]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4])
```

Finally, we are looking to choose `z` number of elements out of those repeated numbers using `np.random.choice()` and without replacement.

Let's say `z = 7` to choose `7` elements, so with `np.random.choice()`, we would have :

```
In [34]: np.random.choice(rep_nums,7,replace=False)
Out[34]: array([2, 4, 0, 2, 4, 1, 2])
```

Now, this `without replacement` term here might sound confusing, as we already have repeated numbers in `rep_nums`. But, what it essentially means is that, the output from `np.random.choice()` mustn't contain e.g. more than two `4's`, because `rep_nums` has two `4's`.

So, the problem is we want to get rid of that `np.repeat` part, which might be a bottleneck for really huge arrays.

### Proposed approach

Looking at the output from `rep_nums`, one idea would be to generate `z = 7` unique elements ranging across the length of `rep_nums` :

```
In [44]: np.random.choice(rep_nums.size,7,replace=False)
Out[44]: array([ 7,  2,  4, 10, 13,  8,  3])
```

These numbers represent indices for that length. So, we just need to look for the bin (out of the `5` bins) in `rep_nums` in which each of those `7`  numbers would go in. For that, we can use `np.searchsorted`. Thus, we would have an implementation to handle generic `x`, `y`, like so -

```
# Get the intervals of those bins
intervals = data.astype(int).cumsum()

# Decide length of array if we had repeated with `np.repeat`
max_num = intervals[-1]

# Get unique numbers (indices in this case)
ids = np.random.choice(max_num,z,replace=False)

# Use searchsorted to get bin IDs and add in `x` offset
out = x+np.searchsorted(intervals,ids,'right')
```

**Runtime test**

Functions :

```
def org_app(x,y,z,data):
    rep_nums = np.repeat(range(x,y), data.astype('int64'))
    out = np.random.choice(rep_nums, z,replace=False)
    return out
     
def optimized_v1(x,y,z,data):     
    intervals = data.astype(int).cumsum()
    max_num = intervals[-1]
    ids = np.random.choice(max_num,z,replace=False)
    out = x+np.searchsorted(intervals,ids,'right')
    return out
```

Timings on full functions -

```
In [79]: # Setup inputs
    ...: x = 100
    ...: y = 10010
    ...: z = 1000
    ...: data = np.random.randint(100,5000,(y-x)).astype(float)
    ...: 

In [80]: %timeit org_app(x,y,z,data)
1 loop, best of 3: 7.17 s per loop

In [81]: %timeit optimized_v1(x,y,z,data)
1 loop, best of 3: 6.92 s per loop
```

Doesn't look like we are getting good speedup. Let's dig deeper and find out how much are we saving on replacing `np.repeat`!

First off the original approach -

```
In [82]: %timeit np.repeat(range(x,y), data.astype('int64'))
1 loop, best of 3: 227 ms per loop
```

Let's see how much improvement we got on this with the proposed approach. So, let's time everything except `np.random.choice()` in the proposed approach -

```
In [83]: intervals = data.astype(int).cumsum()
    ...: max_num = intervals[-1]
    ...: ids = np.random.choice(max_num,z,replace=False)
    ...: out = x+np.searchsorted(intervals,ids,'right')
    ...: 

In [84]: %timeit data.astype(int).cumsum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 36.6 µs per loop

In [85]: %timeit intervals[-1]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 142 ns per loop

In [86]: %timeit x+np.searchsorted(intervals,ids,'right')
10000 loops, best of 3: 127 µs per loop
```

**This is much better than `227ms` from `np.repeat`!!**

So, we are hoping that at really huge arrays, the benefit from removing `np.repeat` would really shine, as otherwise `np.random.choice()` itself looks like the bottleneck.

Comment: Very good answer, and you even explain the problem better than myself :) I had other implementation for this, where I used an hypergeometic sample, but I only do it when the number of classes (y-x) is much smaller than the total number of initial units (data.sum()). However, you solution seems to be fast enough for all cases...

Comment: @DiogoSantos Glad to hear that, took me a while to figure that out :)

Comment: FYI: `intervals` is a cumulative sum of positive numbers, so you could replace `max_num = intervals.max()` with `max_num = intervals[-1]`.

Comment: I was just experimenting a bit with this, and I noticed what I think is a bug.  It looks like you should use `side='right'` in the call to `searchsorted`.  For example, suppose `data` is `[5, 2, 3]`, then `intervals` is `[5, 7, 10]`.   Also suppose `ids` is `range(10)`.  The "classification" of the values in `ids` should be `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]`.  That is what is returned by `np.searchsorted(intervals, np.arange(10), side='right')`.  `side='left'` (the default) results in `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks a lot really! That looked like a bug indeed. Edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

For completion, I also have an alternative implementation. Given that we have `data`, we can use an hypergeometric sampling for each class:

- calculate reverse `data.cumsum()`
- for each class draw `np.hypergeometric(data[pos], cumsum[pos]-data[pos], remain)`

However, when we have many classes with few units in each this takes a long time.

Comment: *"...with few units in each"*  Could you give a concrete example of such an input?  Divakar used `data = np.random.randint(100,5000,(y-x)).astype(float)`.  Is that typical, or does "few units in each" mean the values in in `data` should be much smaller?

Comment: This are cases in which 80% of the entries are between 1 and 100